# Listener Port 1433 for Always on Availability Group

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups, high-availability, listener, hadr

In our Availability group I have a reporting server where report writers will connect directly and also crystal reports will be used, If the listener port is 1433 and the clients also gets connected through port 1433 to the reporting server that is part of the Availability group will there be any port conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the listener port is 1433 and the clients also gets connected through port 1433 to the reporting server that is part of the Availability group will there be any port conflict.

If 1433 is just dedicated to sql server and no other service is using it, there wont be any conflicts.

This is documented well in [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-2017#SelectListenerPort) :

> If you use the default port of 1433 for availability group listener VNNs, you will still need to **ensure that no other services on the cluster node are using this port**; otherwise this would **cause a port conflict**.
>
> If one of the instances of SQL Server is already listening on TCP port 1433 via the instance listener and there are no other services (including additional instances of SQL Server) on the computer listening on port 1433, this will not cause a port conflict with the availability group listener. This is because the availability group listener can share the same TCP port inside the same service process. However multiple instances of SQL Server (side-by-side)should not be configured to listen on the same port.